# Converting numbers 0-9 to images?

Tags: javascript, image, numbers

I'm quite new to JavaScript, but am attempting to write a script that will convert text numbers to an image (of the number). How might I go about this?

P.s. I did find this code online, but it seems wishy-washy.

```
<script language="JavaScript1.1" type="text/javascript">
function phils_image_price(input)
{
//declare variables
var output=""
var position=0
var chr=""
//loop
for (var position=0; position < input.length; position++)
{
chr=input.substring(position,position+1)
//replace
if (chr == '£') {output=output + '<img border="0"
src="img/pound.gif">'}
else if(chr == '0') {output=output + '<img border="0"
src="img/0.gif">'}
else if(chr == '1') {output=output + '<img border="0"
src="img/1.gif">'}
else if(chr == '2') {output=output + '<img border="0"
src="img/2.gif">'}
else if(chr == '3') {output=output + '<img border="0"
src="img/3.gif">'}
else if(chr == '4') {output=output + '<img border="0"
src="img/4.gif">'}
else if(chr == '5') {output=output + '<img border="0"
src="img/5.gif">'}
else if(chr == '6') {output=output + '<img border="0"
src="img/6.gif">'}
else if(chr == '7') {output=output + '<img border="0"
src="img/7.gif">'}
else if(chr == '8') {output=output + '<img border="0"
src="img/8.gif">'}
else if(chr == '9') {output=output + '<img border="0"
src="img/9.gif">'}
else if(chr == '.') {output=output + '<img border="0"
src="img/dot.gif">'}
else {output=output + chr}
}
return output;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript1.1" type="text/javascript">
document.write('£12345678.90')
document.write('<br>')
document.write(phils_image_price('£12345678.90'))
</script>
```

Comment: just a question, why do you wanna do that?

Comment: I'm guessing captcha or something similar ?

Comment: @adeneo It's clearly for making a price; I'm guessing user2364094 wants to achieve something similar to [this](http://riii.nl/w9349) (go ahead, change the numbers in the url).

Comment: if not captcha, what's wrong with covering text with transparent png

Comment: just saw robi's link. Its nice, i'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the interest guys. I'm making a number count-up that increases on a set interval. I want the numbers to show as images because I've designed my own stylized numbers (neon-looking) that I want to appear instead of normal numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function phils_image_price(input) {
    var output = ""

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var chr = input.substring(i, i + 1)
        if (chr == '£') {
            output += '<img border="0" src="img/pound.gif">';
        } else if (chr == '.') {
            output += '<img border="0" src="img/dot.gif">';
        } else {
            output += '<img border="0" src="img/'+(chr+1)+'.gif">';
        }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I'd make sure input is a string, not a float/integer so `.substring()` and `.length` won't fail. Just add a simple `input = input.toString();' or `input = '' + input;` or something before the loop. This is just to handle someone calling the function like `phils_image_price(123.45);` instead of the supposed `phils_image_price('123.45');`. Another option is to 'sniff' an int/float being passed to make sure you also call `.toFixed(2)` when needed. Just a little 'defensive programming', nothing spectacular ;)

Comment: So I'm using this in Wordpress. I've already put the code in a js file enqueued in functions.php, how do I call on the function on a page in wordpress? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function textNumbersToImages(text) {

    var output = '';

    // You could define a list of filenames here
    var images = ['0.gif', '1.gif', '2.gif', '3.gif', 
        '4.gif', '5.gif', '6.gif', '7.gif', '8.gif', '9.gif'];

    // We eliminate all characters that are not a number
    var nums = text.replace(/\D/g, ''); 

    // Now we iterate over all those numbers
    for (var i=0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        output += '<img src="' + images[nums.charAt(i)] + '" />';
    }

    // We return the constructed string, that is a list of image tags
    return output;

};
```